# Xamarin Profiler - Paths To Roots not giving any information

Tags: xamarin, profiler

I'm trying to track down leaks using Profiler, and can see Objects which are 'Live' in a snapshot.

This article:

https://xamarinhelp.com/tracking-memory-leaks-xamarin-profiler/

indicates that the 'Paths To Roots' shows what is holding a reference to the object.

However, I'm finding that there is nothing on the 'Paths To Roots' tab.

Do I need to do something to see this information, or is this a known bug in Profiler?

This a Forms project, running on Android. I'm using Profiler version 1.6.0-25 on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this is only populated *after stopping the profiling session*.

This [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=47171) in the Xamarin Bugzilla has some more information.